# Recommended way to manage page redirection

Tags: php, session, redirect

The redirection method in question sets a session value on each page. As a page is accessed all previous page sessions are unset and a session value for the current page is set. On redirection a function is called which checks on which page the session is set and performs the redirection.

### Detailed Description

1. Unset any page 'access' sessions when first accessing a page by calling `clear_sessions();`

   ```
   clear_sessions(){
       //example
       unset($_SESSION['search_product_page']);
       unset($_SESSION['search_inventory_page']);
   };
   ```
2. Set session on current page

   ```
   $_SESSION['search_inventory_page'] = 1;
   ```
3. Call redirection

   ```
   function redirection(){
       if(isset($_SESSION['search_product_page'])){
           header("Location:search_product.php");
           exit();
       }
       elseif (isset($_SESSION['search_inventory_page'])){
           header("Location:search_inventory.php");
           exit();
       }
   }
   ```

This seems like a very clunky way of doing this. Any recommendations on how I should be handling redirection?

Thanks.

Comment: A note on the markup: You had tab characters mixed with spaces as your whitespace.  SO reacts well to 4 spaces before code.  In your ordered lists, text is expected to be 4 space indented already if it's an item of the list.  Thus, to mark text as code, it needs yet another 4 spaces.  Thus, your code should start with 8 spaces and all tabs needed to be replaced with 4 spaces.  Just FYI.  I've edited for you in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just trying to understand.  Basically, your pages execute steps 1 and 2, run additional code, and then execute step 3 at the end?  If this is so, I would likely do away with abstracting away the redirection into a function.  Or, if you do, at least remove the use of Sessions.  It's messy and unnecessary.  It also reduces readability and makes it less flexible.  You wouldn't easily be able to handle conditional redirects on your page.

I would either insert the `header("Location: ...");` redirect directly in the code or add an argument to the function declaration for `redirection()` that took the current page action.

For example, in a settings file, define your page actions:

```
define("SEARCH_INVENTORY_PAGE__SUBMITTED", 1);
define("SEARCH_PRODUCT_PAGE__SUBMITTED", 2);
```

and in your redirection function, you accept the page action:

```
function redirection($action){
    switch($action) {
        case SEARCH_INVENTORY_PAGE__SUBMITTED:
            header("Location: closedTicket.php");
            break;
        case SEARCH_PRODUCT_PAGE__SUBMITTED:
            header("Location: editTicket.php");
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception('Page action $action not defined.');
    }
    exit();
}
```

and calling the function from you code via the action, e.g.

```
redirection(SEARCH_INVENTORY_PAGE__SUBMITTED);
```

Comment: Hmm..So I thought your solution will work but it doesn't seem to address one of the main issues; for example, I can access the view product page from either the `search_product.php` or `search_inventory.php` page. How would I redirect to the correct page from the `view_product.php` page? I understand that I can pass the `SEARCH_PRODUCT_PAGE__SUBMITTED` constant via the `url` but thats no better than my current solution.

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to return to a page after processing something?  That would be a reasonable use of session variables.  Another way this is done is to pass the return url in as a variable as part of the POST data if you're doing a form submission.  And yes, this could be passed in as a GET variable (i.e. as part of the URL) and it would be sent through as an integer, since that's how the variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect($url) {
    ob_start();
    header("Location:".$url);
    ob_flush();
    die();
}
```

Try this code and you can redirect by calling this function. And this code also

```
if(isset($_SESSION['search_product_page'])){
    redirect("editTicket.php");
    exit();
}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['search_inventory_page'])){
    redirect("Location:closedTicket.php");
    exit();
}
```